# Regex to only allow first occurrence of character

Tags: c#, regex

I have some forms in which users will input some numbers, I want to prevent them from entering more than one comma in this string

I made something like this

```
var input = "1,,,,2";
var value = Regex.Replace(input, ",{1,}", ".");
```

This will output 1.2, which is correct. But if I enter

```
var input = 1,,,2,3,,,4,5,,6
```

everything fails

What id like to do is to form the last version of the input to 1.23456

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Could you call Replace() twice, once to replace the first comma, and again to remove the rest of the commas?

Comment: Why are you replacing the commas with a period? (I'm asking because I hope you're not converting a number in Swedish format like `3 995 000,43` to US format `3,995,000.43` so you can use `decimal.Parse`, instead of using `decimal.Parse` with a Swedish CultureInfo.)

Comment: Im replacing the commas with periods to be able to make calculations, it has nothing to do with number formatting! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace (input, @"(?<=^\d+),", ".").Replace (",", "");
```

This replaces the first `,` comma with a `.` period, then replaces the remaining commas with `empty`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `(?<!,[^,]*?),+`

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!,[^,]*?),+", ".").Replace(",", string.Empty);
```

Or this code:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!,[^,]*?)(,+)|(,+)", 
    m => m.Groups[1].Success ? "." : string.Empty);
```

Output: `1.23456`